# Add a string property to a UIButton in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

How can I associate a string property with a `UIButton` in Swift? I don't want the string to appear as the button text, simply to be assigned to the button as an identifier or a key. Here is what I have so far:

```
func createAnswerButtons() {

    var index:Int
    for index = 0; index < self.currentQuestion?.answers.count; index++ {

        // Create an answer button view
        var answer:AnswerButtonView = AnswerButtonView()
        selection.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        // Place into content view
        self.scrollViewContentView.addSubview(answer)

        // Add a tapped gesture recognizer to the button
        let tapGesture:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("answerTapped:"))
        answer.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        // Add constraints etc

        // Set the answer button text
        let answerText = self.currentQuestion!.answers[index]
        answer.setAnswerText(answerText)

        // Set the identifier for each answer button
        self.identifier = self.currentQuestion!.answerIdentifier[index]

        // Add to the selection button array
        self.answerButtonArray.append(answer)
}
```

So I think I need something after

```
// Set the identifier for each answer
        self.identifier = self.currentQuestion!.answerIdentifier[index]
```

To assign the identifier to the button.

The reason for this is I'm trying to implement a decision tree logic so that I can keep track of each answer button that is tapped to generate a code string that will correspond to a final result.

Comment: why don't you use the tag property ?

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus Tag isn't a string.  It's an `NSInteger`.

Comment: @nhgrif I know that if he is not displaying the text I don't see a need for a string

Comment: brad88, did you try my answer?

Comment: No, I don't know how to make use of that answer! Tried a few times but honestly I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing

Answer (score 10):

You can use the accessibility identifier (`button.accessibilityIdentifier`), if the button you want to identify should have a unique identifier (this matters if you're ever writing UI tests).

You can also subclass UIButton and add a variable `buttonIdentifier`.

```
class IdentifiedButton: UIButton {
    var buttonIdentifier: String?
}
```

Comment: ... and then always remember to use this subclass instead of `UIButton` everywhere on your IB files and such.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info on this as I'm totally stuck!

Comment: I don't have a UIButton as I created the Button Views programmatically. I created a class called AnswerButtonView and now in the view controller I'm creating the button views

Answer (score 10):

Using the Objective-C runtime, we can add properties to classes at runtime:

```
extension UIButton {
    private struct AssociatedKeys {
        static var DescriptiveName = "nsh_DescriptiveName"
    }

    @IBInspectable var descriptiveName: String? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.DescriptiveName) as? String
        }
        set {
            if let newValue = newValue {
                objc_setAssociatedObject(
                    self,
                    &AssociatedKeys.DescriptiveName,
                    newValue as NSString?,
                    UInt(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Adding `@IBInspectable` also lets us set the `descriptiveName` property through Interface Builder.

For more about the Objective-C runtime, I recommend you check out [this NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/swift-objc-runtime/).

Comment: This is a great solution, but its quite hacky and honestly OP doesn't need all `UIButton` instances to include this property. Upboated anyways.

Answer (score 9):

You can use **accessibilityIdentifier** property of UIButton.

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
button.accessibilityIdentifier = "Some useful text"
```

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
button.accessibilityIdentifier = "some text"
```

istead of tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array with the strings you want associated with the button. Then set the buttons tag to the index of the string you want associated with the button. Hence:

```
var myStrings = ["First","Second","Third"]

button.tag = //insert a number corresponding to the string index in myStrings that you want for the button

func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton){
    var selectedString = myString[sender.tag]
}
```

Comment: how to use this?