# How to add a file to project to Subclass UIImage() and add a var named "tag" to my new class

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add a tag to `UIImages` in order to later be able to identify and to find them easily.

I don't know how to do that and I was searching all over the internet. I was hoping someone could help me to achieve this. Maybe using something like that:

```
image.tag = "FirstImage"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a string property to a UIButton in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30214519/add-a-string-property-to-a-uibutton-in-swift) -- the question here (and *both* answers) can be applied to *any* class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem back in Obj-C and with URLs, and someone told me to solve it with a class. Here is how to do it in swift.

You can easily achieve that by creating a `struct or class`. In the following example I’ll just use a class and show you how to achieve the tagging of your pictures.

Firstly, let’s create our class in our view controller.

Under `class ViewController: UIViewController {`
let’s make the class as follow

```
class MyImage 
{
}
```

Now that we have a class, let’s add an image property to it and also the tag you want to add.

```
class MyImage 
{

//the image variable
var img = UIImage(named: “”)

// the tag variable
var imgID : String = “”

}
```

Great. Now that we have this setup, we can start creating images
Now that we have created this class, let’s configure some images.

Wherever you want your image, for example in the `view didLoad` method we create the image like so:

```
let image1 : MyImage
image1.img = UIImage(named :”example.png”)
image1.imgID = “My ID”
```

From here you can easily access every property of our class. 
Hope that helped you. Keep coding.

Comment: Wow... Thank you that looks nearly like a tutorial. I'll check it out ow. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. It works without a problem. The only thing, is there any way to make this shorter? This is pretty much code considering i have 30 images...

Comment: Ehm... You could try with initialisers... But it'll not reduce the amount of code significantly...

Comment: With newer versions of Swift, you can try using an extension of UIImage.

Answer (score -1):

`image.tag = 112` something like this not like string tag is `NSInteger` type. So you can not give string to it.

Comment: `UIImage` doesn't have a `tag` property, are you thinking of a `UIImageView`?